# Git is not installing on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3

Tags: linux, git, perl, suse

Git is not installing on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3.
following error showed up while installing:

perl-Error is needed by git-core-2.12.3-26.1.x86_64

Answer (score 1):

You just need to install `perl(Error)`. But you need to get the right package for your specific distro.

Add the repo to your installation (check for info [here](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=devel%3Alanguages%3Aperl&package=perl-Error)).

It should look something like this, but I would assume that the `addrepo` link **might** have to be different in order for you to get the right `perl-error`

```sh
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:languages:perl/SLE_12_SP4/devel:languages:perl.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install perl-Error
```

and then try installing `git-core` again.